# TYPO3 6.1 using Repositories in Service Class

Tags: php, repository, typo3, typo3-flow, typo3-6.1.x

I am trying to implement an authentication service that authenticates users against an ADLDS. So far, so good. The implementation and activation of the service is not the problem, but I need some features from my Repositories inside the Service.

```
$usergroups = $this->adlds->getTypoGroups($this->login['uname']);
/** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage */
$groupStorage = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\ObjectStorage');
$objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
$plFrontendUserRepository = $objectManager->get('PLE\\PlBase\\Domain\\Repository\\PlFrontendUserRepository');
$languageGroupRepository = $objectManager->get('PLE\\PlBase\\Domain\\Repository\\LanguageGroupRepository');
foreach ($usergroups as $groupname) {
     $groupStorage->attach($languageGroupRepository->findByGroupTitle($groupname));
}
```

When i try to instantiate the repositories with the objectmanager i get " Call to a member function versionOL() on a non-object in ..\Classes\Persistence\Generic\Storage\Typo3DbBackend.php on line 1203"

And when I try to use:

```
/**
 * languageGroupRepository
 * 
 * @var \PLE\PlBase\Domain\Repository\LanguageGroupRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $languageGroupRepository;

/**
 * plFrontendUserRepository
 *
 * @var \PLE\PlBase\Domain\Repository\PlFrontendUserRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $plFrontendUserRepository;
```

And use the two repositories with "$this->repository" i get "Call to a member function findByGroupTitle() on a non-object" (its the function of the repository)... so the injection fails. I even tried to implement the injection functions, but that doesn't work at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might be too early in bootstrap to use the full extbase power. Please try to find out what object is missing. You might need to fill it yourself.

Comment: If I read the source of [Typo3DbBackend->doLanguageAndWorkspaceOverlay](http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/60/html/_typo3_db_backend_8php_source.html#l01097) right, this can only happen if getPageRepository does not return a proper object. Are you manually setting $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_page to something?

Are you using some kind of simulated frontend? Because otherwise I can't even see how the code in Typo3DbBackend could work in all backend contexts correctly. The behaviour you see might be related to using objects with table_name pages.